# Problema com impressão de dados de um array

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo dois arrays row e mailTeste, um deles vem do meu banco de dados e já é populado, dentro dele possui duas tables row["email"] e row["id] que eu quero passar para meu outro array que vai ser usado dentro de um foreach para imprimir os resultados na tela, pretendo usar esse mailTeste para fazer comparações com futuras adições de dados neste banco.

O problema é que não estou conseguindo passar dos dados da row para meu array MailTeste.

```
$query = "SELECT TabelaX.email, TabelaX.id, TabelaY.whitelist FROM email   RIGHT JOIN whitelist ON TabelaX.id = TabelaY.sid WHERE rid='0' ORDER BY email";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$W_list = "";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $Email_ot = array(
        $row["email"] => $row["id"]
    );
}
```

Neste bloco de código de cima eu pego os dados (email e id) do banco e passo para a row, logo após crio o array $mailTeste para guardar as informações.

```
foreach ($Email_ot as $email => $id) {
    if (in_array($email, $wlistTeste)) {
        echo "existe no array<br>";
    } else {
        echo "não existe: ";
        printf($email . '<br>');
    }
}
```

Este foreach é usado para confirmar se os dados que foram colocados dentro de um input ja estão no banco de dados.

Comment: Onde está a array `mailTeste`? Não vi ela no código apresentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que no comando while você está criando um novo array para cada iteração... Então pra cada linha que a consulta retorna, em vez de adicionar no array você apaga o array e cria um array novo.

Você precisa criar a variável `$Email_ot` antes do while e utilizá-la dentro do while.

```
// ...
$Email_ot = array();
while(...) {
    $Email_ot [$row["email"]] = $row["id"];
}
```